# SQL Server sp_add_schedule Active_Start_Date Tomorrow

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, schedule

I am trying to create a job that will run once (tomorrow) at 1:00 AM.  I think this should be pretty easy but I'm not having much luck.

Essentially this is what I would like to do however the DATEADD apparently doesn't work in this context:

```
EXEC sp_add_schedule
@schedule_name = N'WebUpdateOnce',
@freq_type = 1,
@active_start_date = DATEADD(d,1,GETDATE()),
@active_start_time = 010000;    
GO
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

jh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

- You can't set sproc parameters dynamically like that. It'd be nice, but it's a no go.
- The format for @active_start_date is a string of the form YYYYMMDD. Your dateadd will (likely) not produce that.

That said, this worked for me:

```
declare @start_date varchar(8) = convert(varchar(8), DATEADD(day,1,GETDATE()), 112)

EXEC sp_add_schedule
   @schedule_name = N'WebUpdateOnce',
   @freq_type = 1,
   @active_start_date = @start_date,
   @active_start_time = 010000;
```